# Kmeans is not working properly in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cluster-analysis, k-means, image-segmentation

I'm trying to apply Kmeans clustering algorithm on some 2D image in order to cluster different colors regions. As a start, I've taken the exact same example offered by MATLAB here, http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/color-based-segmentation-using-k-means-clustering.html. I have downloaded the image they used and used the same code, except for adding `figure` keyword before the first imshow, because without that the image can't be displayed.

As the example said there must be 3 clusters, white, blue, and pink.  this example also shows the images of each cluster (please take a look at the provided link). In my code, I get a completely different clusters images from those provided in the website. Here is what I get,

[image]

This is my code (almost similar to the one in the website),

```
%Clustering color regions in an image. 

%Step 1: read the image using imread, and show it using imshow. 

img =  (imread('exampleimage.png'));

figure, imshow(img), title('some image'); %figure is for creating a figure window.
text(size(img,2),size(img,1)+15,...
     'some image', ...
     'FontSize',7,'HorizontalAlignment','right');

 %Step 2: Convert Image from RGB Color Space to L*a*b* Color Space
 conversionform = makecform('srgb2lab'); %the form of the conversion is defined as from rgb to l a b
 lab_img = applycform(img,conversionform); %converting the rgb image to l a b image using the conversion form defined above.

 %Step 3: Classify the Colors in 'a*b*' Space Using K-Means Clustering
 ab = double(lab_img(:,:,2:3));
 nrows = size(ab,1);
 ncols = size(ab,2);
 ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,2);

 nColors = 3;

% repeat the clustering 3 times to avoid local minima
[cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(ab,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean', ...
                                      'Replicates',3);


%Step 4: Label Every Pixel in the Image Using the Results from KMEANS

%For every object in your input, kmeans returns an index corresponding to a cluster. The cluster_center output from kmeans will be used later in the example. Label every pixel in the image with its cluster_index.

pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
imshow(pixel_labels,[]), title('image labeled by cluster index');

segmented_images = cell(1,3);
rgb_label = repmat(pixel_labels,[1 1 3]);

for k = 1:nColors
    color = img;
    color(rgb_label ~= k) = 0;
    segmented_images{k} = color;
end

imshow(segmented_images{1}), title('objects in cluster 1');
imshow(segmented_images{2}), title('objects in cluster 2');

imshow(segmented_images{3}), title('objects in cluster 3');
```

Can you please tell me what is causing the problem?

Thank You.

Comment: When I run your code, I get the correct behavior (though it is nicer to add some more `figure` commands so that the `imshow`s don't overwrite each other. Can you display other images correctly? What results when you run the command `imshow(imread('rice.png'))`?

Comment: This is weird the code doesn't produce the cluster images any more, I get this error when I try to run it, Error using kmeans
Too many input arguments.
Error in cluster (line 24)
[cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(ab,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean','Replicates',3); Regarding the first original image I get it in the correct format, but the problem was in the clustering images. Can you please tell me how can I solve it? Thank you.

Comment: @Tokkot, I've placed the code in a new script, and added "figure" before every imshow, it is now working perfectly. If you want you may post the tip of adding figure keyword as an answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm glad to help, but given that this was the solution to your problem, I'm going to flag this question to be closed because it really has nothing to do with K-means.

Comment: @Tokkot I don't see anything wrong with the question, anyone can encounter the same clusters plotting problem. Plus, the question is properly asked and clarified. But, anyway, it's your opinion. Thank you for your help.